Preparing image datasets for a CNN
I'm struggling to decide on how to setup my model. I'm learning by myself so hoping to get some advice.
I am building an image classifier using a CNN with the aim to classify food images as healthy or unhealthy.
For this I have collected a handful of datasets.
Each of these datasets has purely images of healthy or unhealthy food. And within these datasets the images are separated into sub directories, i.e the "healthy dataset" contains subdirectories called "grains", "salads" etc.
I have been trying to use tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory, however this ideally wants to import images in datasets organised with directories with desired labels, whereas in my case I want to label them as healthy/unhealthy, and not use the subdirectory name (e.g "salad).
The reason I don't want to combine the healthy/unhealthy images all together into distinct directories is that I want to equally separate the sub classes across the train/test/validation sets.
Should I be using a different ingestion tool instead/is there another approach I should take?

You can create a custom data generator for this.
